# PHP and MySQL encoding UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

**Hello folks;**

We're having some weird issue with the character encoding:

We're using Notepad++ with UTF+8 without BOM and sending information to the database (mysql):

When inserting: "análisis", it insers "anÃ¡lisis"

Anyone have any idea about how this could be happning?

Thanks in advance!

--

**Edit: If I manually insert the information into the MySQL table, it properly works.**

Comment: What is the character set you are using for the field you are inserting this data into?

Comment: Either (1) you are not settings your connection's character set to MySQL to utf-8 (2) it actually sets the right value but you are not looking in an interface _showing_ it as utf-8 or (3) well, somewhere else in the chain you forgot to use utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

UTF8 EN/DECODE is probably what you need, [Leer > PHP UTF8 EN/DECODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

Also 
`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

And send explicit UTF-8 headers:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to verify the character encoding of the column (which is either explicitly defined on the column, or using the table / database defaults).  Also make sure that no encoding-unsafe functions are modifying the string before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update database charset as follow:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks Mohamed Elbou, the database encoding is working properly, it's the PHP failing somewhere.